# error on importing xmlvm

Tags: java, pdf

I am writing a program in java language using eclipse in that i want to use the

```
 import org.xmlvm.ios.CGPDFDocument;
```

but showing error as `"The import org.xmlvm cannot be resolved"`. Please help how to overcome this error.

Comment: Have you imported corresponding JAR files to build path of eclipse?

Comment: please help me which JAR file to download

Comment: please provide the name of the jar file to overcome the error

Answer (score 0):

You need XMLVM library [found here](http://www.xmlvm.org)

It would be better to create a new project with the provided template

```
xmlvm --skeleton=iphone --out=OUTDIR --app-name=APPNAME
```

You need to properly install XMLVM and have it in your path.

More information about this command line you could [find here](https://sites.google.com/a/xmlvm.org/documentation/#TOC-How-to-start-a-new-project-under-XMLVM)